# pass multiple dataframes through a function simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas

How to pass df10 and df20 (and even more dataframes) through func simultaneously and keep their names for further use?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','d','d','d','g','g','g','g','g','g','k','k','k','k','k','k'],
   'B': [5,5,6,4,5,6,-6,7,7,6,-7,7,-8,7,-6,6,-7,50],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2012,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2014]     
    } );

df10 = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)

df20 = (df['B'] - df['C']).groupby([df.A, df.S]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)

def func(df):
    df1 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
    new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0),['total'] * len(df.columns)))
    df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
    df2 = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
    df2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df2.columns]
    df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('sum_','')
    df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('size_','T')
    return df2
```

EDIT, per request the dataframes printed;

print(df10)
print(df20)

```
df10:

    sum size
S   2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016
A                                       
d   13  6   7   5   6   2   1   1   1   1
g   -11 8   8   8   7   2   1   1   1   1
k   -6  9   48  8   -5  1   1   2   1   1



 df20:

    sum size
S   2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016
A                                       
d   9   4   5   3   4   2   1   1   1   1
g   -15 6   6   6   5   2   1   1   1   1
k   -10 5   40  4   -9  1   1   2   1   1
```

print outs added

Comment: Can you show update your code with a sample of what df10 and df20 look like please?

Comment: I think it would be easiest with a `for` loop over a list of all of the DataFrames that you wish you apply the function to. Though it depends what you wish to do with these DataFrames after `func`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: There is probably a much better way to do this; I just thought I would offer this suggestion. If it is not as required, please let me know, and I will delete.

> How to pass df10 and df20 (and even more dataframes) through func simultaneously and keep their names for further use?

If all you wanted to do is pass multiple functions through `func` and all your data frames are the same format, something as follows may work.

For simplicity take the dataframes:

```
df10 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
df20 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
df30 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
```

and a simple function:

```
your_func(df):
    #### Perform some action/change to df eg
    df2 = df.head(1)
    return df2
```

Create a list of your original dataframes:

```
A = [df10,df20,df30]

A = [   one  two
    0  1.0  4.0
    1  2.0  3.0
    2  3.0  2.0
    3  4.0  1.0,    
        one  two
    0  1.0  4.0
    1  2.0  3.0
    2  3.0  2.0
    3  4.0  1.0,    
        one  two
    0  1.0  4.0
    1  2.0  3.0
    2  3.0  2.0
    3  4.0  1.0]
```

Then, use a for loop to pass each data-frame through a list e.g. This will keep your original dataframes unchanged.

```
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    A[i] = your_func(A[i])
```

Output:

```
A = [
 one  two
0  1.0  4.0,
 one  two
0  1.0  4.0,
 one  two
0  1.0  4.0]
```

So, now the list `A` contains each of the new dataframes. And your original dataframes `df10` `df20` etc remain unchanged. Merely call the elements of `A` to access your new dataframes.

Comment: Alternatively, use map: `newA = map(your_funct, A)` or list comprehension: `newA = [your_func(i) for i in A]`

Comment: @Parfait  - Your way is much cleaner and more efficient. I always forget about map. Thanks for the comment: I'm learning too.

Comment: Thanks guys, however I need to change   the df's and be able to call them individually after warms.

Comment: @Zanshin Can you keep track of their position in the list via their index? Then it will be easy to call them afterwards. Alternatively you could create a new, blank dataframe for as many dataframes that you start with.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @Zanshin If you have your dataframes ordered in the list i.e. `Dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5...]` then when you pass them into your function their order will remain unchanged and you will have `Dfs = [df1_new,df2_new,df3_new,df4_new...]`. Afterwards, to call them individually, simply write `Dfs[i]` where `i is in the range 0 - len(Dfs)` depending on which dataframe you need.